# Fastest way to get openam attribute names for ssoadm

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I am trying to script an openam deployment using ssoadm, and want to know what will be the fastest and fool proof way to get the attribute names for ssoadm?

Right now, i login to the console and "view html source" for the attribute i am interested in, and use that via ssoadm. But, this approach is time consuming, plus with openam13 the attribute names are not available in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in any configuration or service in particular?
For most configurations and services (such as datastores, auth modules, server properties, etc...) there is an ssoadm command that will give you the current values from where you can grab the property names and use the in your script.

For example if you have a Datastore called OpenDJ in your top-level realm you can get the current configuration values using the following command:

```
ssoadm show-datastore -u amadmin -f /tmp/amadmin.pwd -e / -m OpenDJ
```

Typically it's just a matter of finding the right ssoadm command. Another option will be to look at the service definition. All these definitions are kept in xml format in your configuration store inside ou=Services.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For e.g. if i want to set a user profile to "ignored" via ssoadm, i ran the following command: set-realm-svc-attrs --realm / --servicename  iPlanetAMAuthService --attributevalues iplanet-am-auth-dynamic-profile-creation=ignore . But, it took me a while to find out the attribute name for "iplanet-am-auth-dynamic-profile-creation". So, i am trying to find out the most optimal way to get these attribute names (and commands) that i can update or configure via ssoadm

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach is probably to look up the service XML files. At the time of the configuration, the service XML files are all copied over to ~/<OPENAM_HOME>/config/xml folder, so normally you can just try to grep for certain strings (like dynamic), but even then that may not work well.

If you know what service you are dealing with, then things get a bit easier. Are you trying to change an Authentication configuration? It must be defined in amAuth.xml then. The service name to be used for the ssoadm command is defined in the <Service> element under the "name" attribute. The service attribute names are defined under <AttributeSchema> elements with "name" attribute.

Yet another alternative would be to just read the documentation as most of the property names are already documented:
http://openam.forgerock.org/doc/bootstrap/admin-guide/index.html#auth-core-realm-attributes